# 'Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)' errors during runtime of Java application

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

While running a distributed application, I get a lot of these errors on the server as well as on the worker nodes:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f4f8c800000, 549453824, 2097152, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

Most of the time the process continues and finishes as expected but sometimes the process also fails.

I am calling my application with `java -Xms512M -Xmx50G -cp myjar.jar myclass.Main`

The nodes have 128 GBs of RAM where about 120 GBs are free.

I'm using the Oracle JVM:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

What do these messages mean and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: You may not have 512 mb free ram at when running the app `sometimes`. Try removing the -Xms and only keep -Xmx

Comment: Hi. I just tried that but it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Did you upgrade java recently from 1.7.0_41 to 1.7.0_45?

Comment: No I didn't but the nodes are set up just recently. I didn't use 1.7.0_41 for my application yet. Do you think it'll help?

Comment: I've read about people facing this issue when they update java from .41 to 45. I can't tell you for certain but if you can give it a try it might be worth a shot

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I'll try it and will let you know.

Comment: Hi Platypus, unfortunately switching the JDK to the version you said didn't help...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43582/discussion-between-bjorn-jacobs-and-the-platypus)

Comment: I assume that the JVM told the OS "Gimme some more RAM so I can increase heap size", and the OS answered back "No way, Jose".  Precisely why the OS responded that way is hard to say -- you may have bumped into an architectural limit at, eg, 32G.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Platypus suggested in the comments to my question, I downgraded Java to version 1.7.0_41. Unfortunately the problem persisted.

I went even farther back to version 1.7.0_25 and apparently this *solved* the error. I tried it many times and the error message didn't occur a single more time.

Comment: Glad I could help. Do you have any details on why the version change fixed the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. If the problem persists in future Java versions, I'll report a bug to Oracle.